How to use HuggingFace's run_translation.py script to train a translation from scratch?
I tried various HuggingFace scripts to build language models, such as run_mlm.py (link), run_clm.py (link) and run_translation.py (link). For the former 2 scripts, it can train a language model from scratch (i.e. without a base model).
However, I cannot build a model from scratch using run_translation.py, as the model name or path is required in the command line. Given that I have a considerably large parallel translation dataset, how can I build a translation model from scratch?

UPDATE: The command is:
NCCL_P2P_DISABLE="1" NCCL_IB_DISABLE="1" python run_translation.py \
    --output_dir models/TestTranslation-v1 \
    --model_name_or_path fnlp/bart-base-chinese \
    --tokenizer_name path/to/custom-tokenizer \
    --train_file data/bart_parallel/train.json \
    --validation_file data/bart_parallel/validation.json
    --do_train \
    --do_eval \
    --source_lang yue \
    --target_lang zh

p.s. The NCCL_* flags are required for NVIDIA 4090 cards.

several question that you need to clarify 1) do you want to train the model or just use it for predictions? 2) Why you are not considering Google Translate APIs? 3) did you check the manual for translation.py https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/main/examples/pytorch/translation 4) Could you share a command line that you are using?


I want to use the model for translation (prediction of the translated sentences) 2. Google Translate API does not cover low-resource languages 3. the command is updated in the question.


If you only want to do predictions, without training, you need to remove --do_train  flag.

I'm not sure that run_translation.py is the best way to call the model. But here is the solution. Install transformers v4.43 and corresponding run_translation version:
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/transformers/v4.43.2/examples/pytorch/translation/requirements.txt 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/transformers/v4.43.2/examples/pytorch/translation/run_translation.py 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/huggingface/transformers/v4.43.2/examples/pytorch/translation/run_translation_no_trainer.py

pip install transformers==4.43.2
pip install -r requirements.txt

Next run run_translation.py with the following arguments:
NCCL_P2P_DISABLE="1" && NCCL_IB_DISABLE="1" && python run_translation.py \
    --model_name_or_path Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-fr  \
    --source_lang en \
    --target_lang fr \
    --output_dir models/preds \
    --do_eval \
    --do_predict \
    --validation_file input.json \
    --test_file input.json \
    --predict_with_generate=True \
    --max_source_length=512

Where input.json should have the following structure:
[
    {"translation": {"en": "What is your name?", "fr": ""}},
    {"translation": {"en": "Where are you from?", "fr": ""}},
    {"translation": {"en": "Are you local?", "fr": ""}},
    {"translation": {"en": "What is your favourite dish?", "fr": ""}},
    {"translation": {"en": "Do you have a pet?", "fr": ""}},
    {"translation": {"en": "What is your favourite song?", "fr": ""}}
]


But I would like to build a model from scratch, i.e. no base model.

I would advise against this if you didn't train ML models before. You should reuse base models because: 1) You still need to use one of the existing architectures, either it is the BERT or T5 or smth else. Either BERT or T5  will be dowloaded with pretrained weights; 2) There is a thing called "transfer learning" which allows to train models faster on the new data if reusing already trained model;
